# Chrome and Safari iframes on top of each other, not side by side

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, iframe, safari

I know, iframes, what a PITA!

Anyhoos, they work for my needs which are simply a main display frame, and a hidden side frame containing apps that can be called in at any time.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>

<!--Main Style-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site/css/main.css" />

<!--JQuery-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="site/scripts/jquery.js"></script>

<!--BG Colour, Hide Scrollbar and Margins-->
<body bgcolor="cc6666" style="overflow: hidden" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" bottommargin="0">

<!--Page Table, Contains Everything To Keep From Cutting Off iFrame-->
<table height="100%" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">

<!--iFrame Cell-->
<td height="100%">

<!--Main Frame-->
<!--Main frame loads last visited page based on user, unless not logged in then loads welcome page-->

<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['last_visited'])) {
print('<iframe name="frame" src="'.$_SESSION['last_visited'].'" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="bgcolor:white;"></iframe>');
}
else {
print('<iframe name="frame" src="site/welcome.php" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
}
?>

<!--App Frame-->
<!--App frame will be initiated if no user is logged in, or if a user with apps turned on is logged in-->

<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_APPS'])) {
if($_SESSION['SESS_APPS'] == '1') {
    print('<iframe id="app_frame" src="site/apps.php" width="0%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>');
}
}
 else {
print('<iframe id="app_frame" src="site/apps.php" width="0%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>');
}
?>

<!--End iFrame Cell-->
</td>

<!--End Page Table-->
</table>
</body>
```

Hopefully that's not too bad, but the error definitely seem to occur near the bottom, where you have the two iframes printed using php. If I remove the "App Frame" completely, the page is perfect, as I had tested in IE, but if it prints the iframe, then for some reason it prints it below the main frame, rather than to the right.

This happens only in Chrome and Safari, and assume it must be a WebKit thing, as Firefox and IE print the frames side by side, as you would expect.

As I have come to believe, html works on a basis of left to right, unless there is some kind of break at which point it drops down to the next row.

The only reason I can think that in this case that is not what happens, is that the main cell has a width of 100%, meaning antyhing to the right of it is pushed onto the row below.

Can anyone suggest a way I can perhaps mirror the rendering from IE for Chrome and Safari?

NOTE: I don't think it has any bearing on the page this far down, but the entire page is one table, split into two rows. the top row is a table, controlling the layout of my header. The second row is another table, controlling the layout of the frame.

This is because it allows the page to adjust dymaically based on a users resolution, and therefore window size.

Comment: If nothing else, your table's invalid - it's missing the row `<tr>` tag. And you're missing the closing `</head>` and `</html>` tags. Start by making sure your html is valid before blaming browser bugs for the other issues.

Comment: sorry that's actually because I selected parts of my entire page, as I didnt want to post the whole thing as it's quite big. I can assure you the table and head tags are all ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by warpping each iframe in a table cell with a fixed width based on parent table cell.